# AppleScript Parental Control on MAC OS 10.7

Tags: macos, applescript, parental-control

I am trying to write a simple applescript to allow apps ("Address Book") for my guest user account through parental control.
So I start from beginning, I have System Preference/parental control open, I unlock to give authorization. 
The following applescript should check the Address Book.

```
    tell application "System Events"
            tell process "System Preferences"
                    tell window "Parental Controls"
                            click checkbox "Address Book" of row 3 of outline "Allowed Apps:" of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 
                    end tell
            end tell
    end tell
```

The problem I have is this script does not check the checkbox,  and I am sure the path  row 3 of outline "Allowed Apps:" of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 is correct. Anyone got idea why this simple script not working.